# Emacs Wanderlust filter folder

Tags: wanderlust

I am new to Wanderlust so I've started configuring my wanderlust, but there's one thing I don't really understand, and that's how to add filters.
The documentation tells me that the syntax is the following:
`‘/’ condition ‘/’ target-folder`
I have no problem understanding the syntax, I just don't now where to write these filter, in which file, I've tried ~/.folder but that doesn't seem to work, it simply creates a folder in wanderlust called `‘/’ condition ‘/’ target-folder`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A filter folder doesn't copy or move messages — it is just a view into an existing folder, and modifying a message in a filter folder (e.g. marking it as read) will modify the same message in the target folder.

In order to transfer messages from a source folder into a different folder when performing a search, you need to combine a filter folder with a pipe folder.  For example, the following will transfer matching messages from the `+inbox` folder into the `+from-root` folder whenever it is selected:

```
|/from:root/+inbox/|+from-root
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry. I misread it,  `‘/’ condition ‘/’ target-folder` , I understood `target-folder` as a destination folder.
Once again I'm so sorry for my stupid question.

So everything is working. But I'm under the impression that when the condition is met it doesn't move said email but copies it and so it is still present in the `target-folder`.

Comment: Please consider making your answer more useful to future readers of this thread so that if they want to configure the `.folders` with a condition / target, they know how to do it.  You might even want to link to the Wanderlust documentation sheet that gives an example of how to do this correctly.  I know how to configure the filters and have several in my own setup, but to be quite honest, reading your question / answer is not helpful.  Here is one of my old questions/answers:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517677/wanderlust-emacs-filters-format-of-the-string-sincexofdays-inbox